# Can't update from 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect-manager

I find the update workflow always very difficult in Magento. Most likely I'm not doing it correctly ;)
I go to the Magento connect manager. I hit the 'Check for updates' button.
After a while I see new versions of the packages are available.
I'm especially interested in the Magento Core updates so I select 'Mage_All_Latest' which is now at '1.9.2.2 (stable)' and select '1.9.2.3' in the select box.
Now I click the 'Submit changes' button and I wait.
The progress box is filled with messages about lib_* packages and other core packages not compatible with '1.9.2.3'

Isn't this the appropriate work flow? If not what is the use of the Connect Manager? I remember having the same issue when upgrading from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2.2 but evantually got it working. I don't remember how it did that, though ;)

Answer (score 4):

I update via

1. download from magento.com
2. make sure VCS is clean, no changed files
3. copy all files over
4. commit

If you have changes in `.htaccess` and `index.php` it might be worth to check afterwards.

And of course you don't have core hacks.

Comment: I can't understand why it is so difficult for Magento to update itself. It seems I'm not the only one with problems/questions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73476/the-right-way-to-upgrade-magento-ce
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98371/magento-upgrade-conflicts-1-9-2-2-to-1-9-2-3
We're not trying to upgrade a major version, just applying a patch ;(

Comment: Simple answer: You don't update live systems. Even if you run magento connect on your locale package you can't be sure that the HTTP stuff works as expected. HTTP is not made to update software...

Comment: You aren't patching, you are doing a major upgrade (all files overwritten) and Magento is often a complete fail at doing that. If you were just applying a patch, you would have downloaded the patch file and had it done in about 15 minutes (as long as there isn't any weird fluffing of the files that causes hunk failures).

Answer (score 0):

Check if at the top of your prompt, it doesn't throw an error about not being able to delete `pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt`. In my case, I deleted the file manually, re-ran the upgrade and it worked fine.

If it's not the case, Fabian's solution will work for you regardless